# Why does qmake select the "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" run time library for vcapp template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qmake

I have the following qmake project file (test.pro):

```
CONFIG += debug
TEMPLATE = vcapp

SOURCES = temp.cc
```

I ran qmake with the following command in a cygwin shell:

```
env QMAKESPEC=${QT_ROOT}/mkspecs/win32-msvc2010 ${QT_ROOT}/bin/qmake.exe -o test.vcxproj test.pro
```

I opened the .vcxproj file in Visual Studio 2010 and looked at the value of "Runtime Library". It's set to **Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)**. That was a surprise. Shouldn't it have been set to **Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)**? After all, my template is `vcapp`, not `vclib`.

Do I need to change some other setting to instruct qmake to generate a .vcxproj file that uses **Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)**?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: https://qt-project.org/faq/answer/why_does_a_statically_built_qt_use_the_dynamic_visual_studio_runtime_librar

Answer (score 2):

Thanks are due to Hans Passant for providing the link.

From https://qt-project.org/faq/answer/why_does_a_statically_built_qt_use_the_dynamic_visual_studio_runtime_librar

> Qt is built using the -MD(d) switch, which links against the dynamic C/C++ runtime libraries. This is necessary as we have experienced memory problems when using anything but the -MD(d) flag, and in general, it is recommended to use. You should not alter this flag yourself for your application, because it conflicts with how the Qt library is built if you change the flag to -MT. You should not change it for Qt either, since it is likely to cause problems.
>
> Qt is still built statically when using the -static option though, meaning you do not need to distribute the Qt dlls when deploying your application. You will have to distribute the C runtimes though (if they don’t already exist on the target machine), see our deployment documentation [qt.nokia.com].
>
> If you choose to change this setting anyway, then it can be done in the qmake.conf file for your qmakespec. Where it says -MD you need to change it to be -MT. For Visual Studio 2005 it is also necessary to change the relevant files in mkspecs/features to remove the call to mt.exe. As stated above, we can’t support you with any problems you run into as a consequence of making these changes.